# Npm private Registry Verdaccio - publish @types

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I've installed Verdaccio as private npm repository.

I followed this tutorial [How to Create and Publish an npm module in TypeScript](https://codeburst.io/https-chidume-nnamdi-com-npm-module-in-typescript-12b3b22f0724).

Now I can see my private library from the Verdaccio website, and If I type `npm install mypluralize`  it will be installed in node_modules without any problems.

The last command of the tutorial is this: `npm i @types/mypluralize -D`

but this command doesn't work and I cannot use my private library.

What I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the url to your repo in your `.npmrc` under `registry=URL`?

Comment: I used this command: `npm set registry http://myverdacciohost:4873` and in .npmrc I can see : `registry=http://myverdacciohost:4873/`. However I don't think that the problem is related to reach my private npm registry but how I've deployed my private library.

Comment: Here verdaccio maintainer, please show us more log output using npm debug arguments as `npm publish -ddd` and also verdaccio log output would be useful.

Comment: I've re-deployed Verdaccio and everything is working now. No clue on what happened.